# jquery ajax with array of html elements

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have search jquery docs and SO but I can't find exactly what I am after.

I have spans created in php so they follow the pattern of:

```
<span class="om" id="o_1"></span>
<span class="om" id="o_3"></span>
...
```

I want to collect all the numbers in the id attribute and send them as an array of data (json if needs be) to the server via ajax and return the result to a function:

```
$.get("/pages/gOboxMeters", function($("span.om") <-- extract id's here ) {alert(data);} )
```

I am just `alert`ing it for now.

What is the right code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/),

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m2TFv/)**

```
numbers = $('.om').map(function(){
  return this.id.replace('o_', '');
}).get().join(',');

jQuery.get( "/pages/gOboxMeters", "yourVariable: " + numbers,
     function(){alert(""sent);
});
```

*You can use other delimiter character in join*

Comment: I would do `.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')` for extra robustness but +1. Also, the `var` keyword to avoid a global.

Comment: @karim79 so does the get function do the ajax? (do I put the url in there?) or do I just pass 'numbers' as the data? Excellent concise answer BTW

Answer (score 1):

You can also create an `array` and `push` in the value in that array with `each` function of `jQuery`

[**See Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YXB5h/)

```
var num = new Array;

$(".om").each(function(){
       num.push($(this).attr("id").replace("o_",""));
       $("#result").append($(this).attr("id").replace("o_","")+"<br>"); // just to show result visually
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can collect and send the value like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var value = []

$('span.om').each(function(){    
 value.push($(this).attr('id'))});
alert(value);
   $.get("/pages/gOboxMeters",{value : value }, function(){});

});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/1120/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.each()` jQuery function:

```
  var arr = [];
  $('span.om').each(function(index, item){arr.push($(item).attr('id').substring(2));})
```

In this very same page's console I tried the following, and it works right:

```
var arr = []
$('.mainnavs a').each(function(index, item){arr.push($(item).attr('id').substring(4));})
```

After this, use the arr variable for further processing.